# How to only export results of code blocks and not the code that generates it

Tags: org-mode

I'd expect

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file foo.png :exports results
foo -> bar: JSON request
foo -> batz : instantiate batz\npassing resources from request
#+end_src
```

to only produce the resulting image in the exported document, but it exports both the plantuml code that produces it and the resulting image.

Any ideas what I can do to only export the images that are generated by the code block short of commenting out the code blocks after first generating the images?

Comment: Add [:exports results](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Exporting-Code-Blocks) header argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment so will provide an answer: this works fine for me with org 9.3.7 (i.e. only the image is exported, at least to PDF via LaTeX) so maybe it's a bug in the version of org you are using?

If posting this annoys anybody, I will delete.

Comment: Thanks, it is good information to have and appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you could clarify: what version of org are you using and what is your export target (PDF, HTML, ...)? It might help get you a proper answer.

Comment: I don't see your answer.  Did it get deleted?